# Internet from 3G phone to PC, trying to share internet through LAN port to router

Tags: windows-7, router, lan, tethering, ics

[I posted over on Reddit for help first](http://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/15oypz/trying_to_share_tethered_internet_connection/), but ultimately the issue is unresolved. Anyone trying to help may want to look at the conversation I had over there.

I'm on Win7x64, Enterprise N. Ultimately, I'm trying to get my PC, connected to the internet with a 3G cellphone by USB, to share the internet connection with my router, which can then share it over the wireless. I've done this before, but I can't remember whatever I did to ultimately get it to work. However, I may be using a different NIC driver, and I am using a different Cellphone and a different driver for it. But the connection information and method is the same. (I also just attempted to use the old phone and driver, but nothing is appearing to be any different).

When I had it working before, I had the PC connected to the router's Modem port, but the person attempting to help me on Reddit says that shouldn't matter. He also recommended that I ignore the router for the time being, because ICS isn't set up right on my computer. Right now I have my PS3 in it's place, connected to my PC's NIC card with a non-crossover ethernet cable. (I don't have one, and didn't when I had this stuff working before... but that may be an issue...)

My understanding at the moment is that there should maybe be a drop down box on the Sharing tab for my internet connection's properties, but there isn't. There also isn't even a sharing tab on the LAN's properties.

I've easily spent 6+ hours on this yesterday (and now another 2 today, and I'm not even going to count past attempts to restore the setup where I just gave up.)

I'm willing to provide any information or screenshots I can. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What OS is the phone?

Comment: The phone I've trying with now is a Pantech Ease. The phone I was using previously was an LG something. They're just typical phones. Not an Android or iPhone, or smart phone or anything.

You install the driver, attach a USB cord between one of them and the PC, enter the dial-up info, and click connect, and then your computer has internet. I've been using them for years, and I've never seen anything on the phones themselves that I could configure that might effect anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the link between your phone and computer working, all you should need to do is:
*Make sure your PC is connected via Ethernet to either the PS3 or your router's internet port
*Open the Network and Sharing Center
*Click your Local Area Connection
*Click Properties
*Click Sharing
*Use the drop-down to select the network connection created by your phone tether
*Check the checkbox

Now, this connection will hardly be the most reliable thing in the world and your uplink/downlink speeds are going to suffer dramatically, but it should work.